# Trying to turn brush stokes into something so i can move it without lag

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, brush, wacom

I could not find a font that I liked so I kind of made my own. However I used so many strokes with my brush that it makes ai very laggy when i try to downsize, move etc. I was just wondering whether there was a way to make it into like a shape. I tried convert to shape but it did not really work.
Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Select All
- `Object > Expand Appearance` (If Available)
- `Object > Expand`
- Click the **Merge** button on the **Pathfinder Panel**.

Comment: That in fact made it worse... :(

Comment: How so? That should have converted all the separate brush strokes to solid objects with *less* anchors.

Comment: I do have them grouped already, that could be what was wrong. I'll try again when they are ungrouped.

Comment: Just tried it again, it creates even more lag for some reason..

Comment: Expand as described above, then save the file. Then relaunch Illustrator.

Comment: I did what you said and it did not work. However I tried it on another word I did the exact same with the brush etc, and it worked. I'm very confused rn